# SQL - Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax - WITH

Tags: sql, syntax-error, with-statement

I am struggling because the code i have done is not working

I always get an error with my syntax :
"Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'SELECT SUM(order_amount) as gms,  SUM(order_amount*fees_percentage) as ar,  SUM(' at line 2"

**This is my code:**

```
WITH totals AS(
    SELECT SUM(order_amount) as gms,
    SUM(order_amount*fees_percentage) as ar,
    SUM(order_amount*(fees_percentage - payment_cost_percentage) as gm, 
        FROM data
        WHERE has_discount > 0
SELECT
gms/SUM(order_amount) AS GMS,
ar/SUM(order_amount*fees_percentage) AS ar,
gm/SUM(order_amount*(fees_percentage - payment_cost_percentage) AS gm, 
FROM data
               LEFT JOIN totals ON data.retailer_id = totals.retailer_id)))
```

I tried many things but nothing is working, someone can explain me ?

Thank you

Update : I corrected it :

```
WITH totals AS(
SELECT SUM(order_amount) AS gms,
 SUM(order_amount*fees_percentage) AS ar,
 SUM(order_amount*(fees_percentage - payment_cost_percentage)) AS gm
FROM data
WHERE has_discount > 0)
SELECT
 gms/SUM(order_amount) AS GMS,
 ar/SUM(order_amount*fees_percentage) AS ar,
 gm/SUM(order_amount*(fees_percentage - payment_cost_percentage)) AS gm
FROM data
LEFT JOIN totals ON data.retailer_id = totals.fees_percentage
```

But now i have an issue with this error :
Error Code: 1054. Unknown column 'totals.fees_percentage' in 'on clause'

i don't know how to figure it out

Comment: `SUM(order_amount*(fees_percentage - payment_cost_percentage)` doesn't have enough closing parentheses.

Comment: Your `WITH` clause is also missing a closing parenthesis.

Comment: Thank you, i did not see this error, but now i can figure it out for the other error

Comment: You don't have a field called `fees_percentage` in the `SELECT` clause for `totals`. You need to add it if you want to be able to access `data.fees_percentage` as `totals.fees_percentage`.